# How to import local project into JBPM business central instead of using GIT

Tags: jbpm

How to import local project into JBPM business central instead of using GIT.
Getting exception when providing local business-application-kjar path.

Answer (score 2):

- go to the project directory and execute below git commands

  - git init .
  - git add .
  - git commit -m "commit message"
- copy the project directory location and go to business central and click on import project and paste the copied directory location into the repository url and click on import.

make sure you execute all the git command inside the project directory and the copied location should be inside the project directory.

Comment: I would like to import local project not from GIT repo